# What would happen if i took the throttle plate off my 5.3L V8 engine?

Tags: engine, engine-theory, air-intake

The throttle body helps regulate air right? Can't it also restrict air as well. For example put your hand over your mouth and try to breath in. If I took it off wouldn't I be able to get more air in the engine for a greater combustion thus more power and torque.

Comment: You can simulate removing the throttle body by putting the accelerator pedal to the floor. This makes shifting into gear and stopping more difficult, which is why the engineers were nice enough to fit the engine with a throttle body that allows partial throttle application.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbiNndfNNKI shows an example of what happens in this case.

Comment: Regarding the comparison with breathing: what is the reason why you are not always running as fast as you can?

Answer (score 6):

No. Simply put, the throttle body is the physical device that controls engine speed. Thus the name "throttle body" because it throttles the engine.

In essence, if you took the plate off, the engine would run wide open (max RPM) and you would have no control of the engine speed.

It is more complicated than that because there are sensors detecting the air flow and the throttle position, etc. It would likely run poor.

Replacing the throttle body with a high-performance version will help with what you are wanting to do.

[Throttle Body - Explained](https://youtu.be/wmrvnZT4aDU)